# ¿Como hago que vuelva a pedir la contraseña, cuando esta incorrecta?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cajero{  
    public static void main (String [] args){  
        Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);   
        int n, pass;  
        double num, num2, pesos, dolares, R;   
        System.out.println("Ingrese la Contraseña... ");  
        pass = enter.nextInt();  
            if (pass==8520){  
               System.out.println("Contraseña correcta!");  
               System.out.println(" -MENU DE OPCIONES- ");  
               System.out.println("1- PESOS A DOLARES: ");  
               System.out.println("2- DOLARES A PESOS: ");  
               n=enter.nextInt();  
               switch(n){  
                case 1:  
                    System.out.println("--Selecciono PESOS A DOLARES--");  
                    System.out.println("Ingrese los PESOS: ");  
                    pesos = enter.nextDouble();  
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de cambio: ");  
                    num = enter.nextDouble();  
                    R=pesos/num;  
                    System.out.println("Sus dolares son: "+R);  
                    break;  
                case 2:  
                    System.out.println("--Selecciono DOLARES A PESOS--");  
                    System.out.println("Ingrese los DOLARES: ");  
                    dolares = enter.nextDouble();  
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de cambio: ");  
                    num2 = enter.nextDouble();  
                    if (num2==0){  
                        System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre 0");  
                    }  
                    else {  
                    R=num2*dolares;  
                    System.out.println("Sus pesos son: "+R);  
                    }  
                    break;  
                default:  
                    System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion correcta.");     
               }  
                    }  
            else {  
                System.out.println("Contraseña INCORRECTA");  

            }  

    }  
}
```

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Tomé tu código, y agregué un bucle [do-while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) pra que se repita la acción hasta que ingrese una contraseña. Comenté sobre el código en las partes relevantes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cajero {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner enter = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pass;
        System.out.println("Ingrese la Contraseña... ");
        pass = enter.nextInt();
        //uso de do-while para repetir el proceso mientras la contraseña sea incorrecta
        do {
            if (pass == 8520) {
                menu(enter);
            } else {
                //si la contraseña es incorrecta se solicita ingresar nuevamente
                System.out.println("Contraseña INCORRECTA");
                System.out.println("Ingrese la Contraseña nuevamente");
                pass = enter.nextInt();

                if (pass == 8520) {
                    menu(enter);
                }

            }

        } while (pass != 8520);

    }

    private static void menu(Scanner enter) {
        int n;
        double pesos;
        double num;
        double R;
        double dolares;
        double num2;
        System.out.println("Contraseña correcta!");
        System.out.println(" -MENU DE OPCIONES- ");
        System.out.println("1- PESOS A DOLARES: ");
        System.out.println("2- DOLARES A PESOS: ");
        n = enter.nextInt();
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("--Selecciono PESOS A DOLARES--");
                System.out.println("Ingrese los PESOS: ");
                pesos = enter.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de cambio: ");
                num = enter.nextDouble();
                R = pesos / num;
                System.out.println("Sus dolares son: " + R);
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("--Selecciono DOLARES A PESOS--");
                System.out.println("Ingrese los DOLARES: ");
                dolares = enter.nextDouble();
                System.out.println("Ingrese el tipo de cambio: ");
                num2 = enter.nextDouble();
                if (num2 == 0) {
                    System.out.println("No se puede dividir entre 0");
                } else {
                    R = num2 * dolares;
                    System.out.println("Sus pesos son: " + R);
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ingrese una opcion correcta.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose Felipe Charbel por tu respuesta!

Comment: Sería bueno reflexionar en si una respuesta de puro código sin explicación realmente está ayudando a OP a la larga.

Comment: Hola Jose, podrias explicar porque esto es la respuesta?

Comment: Acabo de comentar los fragmentos de codigo que agregue.

Comment: Se recomienda a parte de eso que añadas en qué falló, y porque fallaba su código.

Comment: @JoseFelipeCharbelPavezGass avisa que agregaste    **do-while** *para repetir el proceso mientras la contraseña sea incorrecta*